# ASP Textbox default invisible and visible from JS

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have a textbox which will be initally invisible and checkbox  OnClick JS method , I want the button to be visible ,

initally the checkbox seems invisible but when i click on the checkbox, JS Method gives me the error with object not found. and if i remove the Visible="false" from textbox code works fine.

```
<asp:Textbox id="day" runat="server" Visible="false" />

 <asp:CheckBox ID="parts" runat="server" onClick="Click();" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function Click(){
 document.getElementById("day").style.visibility = "visible";

 //ERROR **0x800a01a8 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required**
 }
  </script>
```

//ERROR **0x800a01a8 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required**

Comment: Setting `Visible="false"` on a server side control means that it will never be rendered to the browser.

Comment: if I set on onload function this happens the same.. I am getting the same error in javascript

Comment: If you view the output page in your browser, you will also note the textbox id is not `"day"`. You need to also set `clientid="day"` or change the ID generation method.

Comment: You can also try getElementById('<%= day.UniqueId %>') or getElementById('<%= day.ClientID %>')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `visible=false`, that is never rendered on page, implies, you can not do `document.getEle..`, it will always give you `null` value and hence , it will throw error.

> If this property is false, the server control is not rendered. - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible(v=vs.100).aspx)

**How to solve this**

So it make it work, you need to make it hidden using javascript and then make it visible using javascript.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="day" runat="server" style="display:none;" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="parts" runat="server" onClick="Click();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Click() {
        document.getElementById("day").style.display = "block"; // use "none" to hide
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the static id mode instead, to stop it using an auto-generated `id`:

e.g.

```
<asp:Textbox id="day" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Visible="false" />
```

Also as you tagged this as jQuery the simpler jQuery could would look like this (if the code follows the elements on the page):

```
   $('#day').click(function(){
       $(this).show();
   });
```

or this if the code precedes the elements, wrap it in a DOM ready handler:

```
$(function(){
       $('#day').click(function(){
           $(this).show();
       });
});
```

`$(function(){...});` is just a handy shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){...});`